# 「Rails の Cache-Control 設定のデフォルト値について」の質問の削除を取り消したい

Tags: サポート, 完了

[Rails の Cache-Control 設定のデフォルト値について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/72493)

上記の質問は現在 Community Bot により削除された状態ですが、自分は回答ができると思っているので、削除を取り消して回答したいと思っています。

3票の削除取り消し票があれば改めて回答可能な状態になるところ、現在は1票だけ入っている状況です。誰か協力してくださる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか?

自分も削除取り消しに投票したいのですが、モデレータ権限では削除投票すると一発で取り消しが成立してしまい、それはちょっと権限の乱用な気がするので、ここに提起しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2021-01-10 11:50 時点で質問の削除が取り消されていました。